# Get Data From a temporary Table Created by Equi Join Query

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table created by an equijoin sql query
but i am unable to get data from that table
I am fetching data from that table from a query string 
please check code here

```
<style type="text/css">
a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.Menu
{
    width:150px;
    float:left;
}
.fr
{
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
    float:right
}

</style>
<div class="Menu">
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","dbname","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$sql="select * from NSEIndices_latest";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$tpnt=$row['TickerPlantCode'];  //nse indice code
$indexname=$row['IndexName']; //nse indice index name
?>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://mastertrade.in/master/wpfiles/gtnsegainers.php?tpnt=<?php echo $tpnt;?>&indexname=<?php echo $indexname;?>" target="fr"><?php echo $indexname;?></a><br></td>
  </tr>
    <?php }?>
    </div>
    <div class="fr">
    <iframe height="780" width="780" scrolling="no" name="fr"></iframe>
    </div>
```

The above page pas a query sting
according to that query string the data is fetched from the temporary table
the page that contain data retrieval code from temporaray table is gtnsegainers.php

```
<table class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Company Name
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">High
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Low
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Last Price
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Prv Close
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Change
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">%Gain
      </th>
  </tr>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","dbname","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$tpnt=$_GET['tpnt'];
$indexname=$_GET['indexname'];
echo "1".$indexname. "<br>";
$query="SELECT nsepricequotes_latest.Symbol, nsepricequotes_latest.CompanyName, nsepricequotes_latest.HighPrice, nsepricequotes_latest.LowPrice, nsepricequotes_latest.LastTradedPrice, nsepricequotes_latest.ClosePrice, nsepricequotes_latest.NetChange, nsepricequotes_latest.PercentChange, nse_index_constituents.Tickerplant_index_code,nse_index_constituents.NSE_Index_Name
FROM nsepricequotes_latest, nse_index_constituents
WHERE nsepricequotes_latest.TickerPlantCode = nse_index_constituents.TickerPlant_scrip
AND PercentChange >0
ORDER BY PercentChange DESC ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo "2".$indexname. "<br>";
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$Symbol1=$row1['Symbol'];
$CompanyName1=$row1['CompanyName'];
$HighPrice1=$row1['HighPrice'];
$LowPrice1=$row1['LowPrice'];
$LastTradedPrice1=$row1['LastTradedPrice'];
$ClosePrice1=$row1['ClosePrice'];
$NetChange1=$row1['NetChange'];
$PercentChange1=$row1['PercentChange'];
$Tickerplant_index_code1=$row1['Tockerplant_index_code1'];
$NSE_Index_Name1=$row1['NSE_Index_Name'];
}
echo "3".$indexname. "<br>";
$tbl="create TEMPORARY TABLE temppice(Symbol varchar(100),CompanyName varchar(200),HighPrice float(50),LowPrice float(50),LastTradedPrice float(50),ClosePrice float(50),NetChange float(50),PercentChange float(50),Tickerplant_index_code varchar(100),NSe_Index_Name varchar(100))";
mysql_query($tbl);
$intbl="Insert into temppice values('$Symbol1','$CompanyName1','$HighPrice1','$LowPrice1','$LastTradedPrice','$ClosePrice1','$NetChange1','$PercentChange1','$Tockerplant_index_code1','$NSE_Index_Name1')";
mysql_query($intbl);
echo "4".$indexname. "<br>";
$query1="Select * from temppice where NSE_Index_Name='$indexname'";
$result1=mysql_query($query1);
if(mysql_error())die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
$symbol=$row['Symbol'];  
$CompanyName=$row['CompanyName'];
$HighPrice=$row['HighPrice'];
$LowPrice=$row['LowPrice'];
$previousclose=$row['LastTradedPrice'];
$ClosePrice=$row['ClosePrice'];
$netChange=$row['NetChange'];
$percentagechange=$row['PercentChange'];
?>

  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $CompanyName;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $HighPrice;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $LowPrice;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $previousclose; ?></td>
   <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $ClosePrice;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $netChange;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $percentagechange;?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

the error am getting is

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/mastertr/public_html/master/wpfiles/gtnsegainers.php on line 53
```

Answer (score 0):

Your queries for creating the table and inserting data check out syntactically and in testing but you should add some error checking there:

```
$tbl="create TEMPORARY TABLE temppice(Symbol varchar(100),
  CompanyName varchar(200),HighPrice float(50),LowPrice float(50),
  LastTradedPrice float(50),ClosePrice float(50),NetChange float(50),
  PercentChange float(50),Tickerplant_index_code varchar(100),
  NSe_Index_Name varchar(100))";

$res = mysql_query($tbl);

if (!$res) { die('Temporary table creation failed: ' . mysql_error()); }
```

Do the same for your insert statement.

Comment: i tried now am getting this
' mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/mastertr/public_html/master/wpfiles/gtnsegainers.php on line 58'